# error making a custom CSR on windows 10. "One or more of the object's properties are missing or invalid"

Tags: windows-10, ssl, certificate, mmc

I am trying to generate a custom CSR using mmc & certificates snap in.  The cert will be a mTLS client cert using ECC.  I go through the following steps:

1. load certificates snap in for current user
2. Right click on "personal" logical store and choose All Tasks -> Advanced Operations -> Create custom request
3. Under Enrollment Policy Proceed without enrollment policy.
4. Custom Request Template (No template) CNG key, supress default extensions, PKCS#10
5. Certificate Properties
   Subject: CN=foo-not-a-FQDN, O=<my company name), OU=, E=
   Extensions: Key usage = Digital Signature
   Extended Key Usage = Client Authentication

And that's it.  No symmetric algorithm and no custom extensions.
Click on the Private key tab and I get
Error "One or more of th eobject's properties are missing or invalid"

And I can open the Private Key tab but all of the options are insensitive.

Why? The DN fields should not matter to the CSR, the CA may have policies regarding what is required but this is just a CSR.  Pretty much anything goes.  Key usage and extended key usage are what is required for ECDH but again the CSR shouldn't be checking that.